# how to add translation tokens to facebook app using canvase page?

Tags: facebook

I was wondering if there is a way to add translation tokens to a Facebook app that was developed using canvas page. Facebook documentation provides fbml method only.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

Facebook's translation application has been riddled with bugs since it's inception and no one seems to be maintaining it or the documentation.  If you want to make your application run in multiple languages you have to implement that yourself.

Here's a list of every FBML tag that is recognized with the javascript API:  http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.XFBML.parse .